# Conditioning VS Code settings property on preferred system color theme

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to set a property in VS Code settings such that it conditions on the system's preferred color theme.

VS Code allows you to detect color scheme by setting `workbench.autoDetectColorScheme` to `true`. Then you can set color themes for the properties - `workbench.preferredLightColorTheme` and
`workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme`.

Is there any way to set properties like `terminal.background` such that they change along with the workbench color theme?

Comment: you can customize based on the name of the Theme

Comment: Can you elaborate? How do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71077432/upper-case-color-problem-in-monokai-pro-theme-in-vs-code/71079456#71079456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [@rioV8's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71087847/conditioning-vs-code-settings-property-on-preferred-system-color-theme/71091516#comment125669939_71087847) suggestion I was able to solve this as follows:

```json
{
  "window.autoDetectColorScheme": true,
  "workbench.preferredLightColorTheme": "Small Aperture",
  "workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme": "Large Aperture",
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Small Aperture]": {
      "terminal.background": "#F2F7F2",
      //...
    },
    "[Large Aperture]": {
      "terminal.background": "#141414",
      //...
    },
  },
}
```

Similar to a CSS media query, you can set different properties for different color themes by using their name inside square brackets.

Unfortunately, you'll have to add sections for all the themes you regularly use.

Comment: While this works for the `terminal.background`, it doesn't work for arbitrary settings. E.g. I'd like to use it for `latex-workshop.view.pdf.invert` to only invert the colours under a dark theme.